# Ajax is submitting the text, but not able to submit HTML data

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am working on a code that will fetch the data from textarea and submit it through ajax on button click.

In next step, PHP will create a file on server and store the ajax data into file.

I have already tried addslashes function of PHP, but that is not working.

I have tried to do it via the above method and its submitting the **text data** successfully. But the issue is with HTML data. I think it must be a parsing problem.

The HTML code

```
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="savebutton" onclick="makePage()"></a>
```

The Javascript code with Ajax

```
<script>

    function makePage(){
    var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value; 
    alert (comment);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
    }
    var content = comment;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","makePage.php?content=" + content,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

And Finally the PHP code

```
<?php
$content = $_GET["content"];
$file = uniqid() . ".html";
file_put_contents("userdata/$file", $content);
echo $file;
?>
```

I am not getting any error message

Comment: Post the data instead of get, and add the data to pass as an argument to `.send`.

Comment: Tried with post, but unfortunately not working

Comment: Post will work, but you've to read from `$_POST` in the PHP code. It also looks like you should sanitize the user input before storing it to your server.

Comment: I tried both part, it is working but again not sending the HTML data. It is working ok for text data.

Comment: When you post HTML, try to `echo $content` and check if any of your HTML code is breaking the content or it is displaying correctly. If that is correct, the file should get created properly. I doubt something in HTML is preventing $file or file_put_contents code to get processed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with POST instead of GET, like Teemu said:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

This row set the right header.

```
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="savebutton" onclick="makePage()">test</a>

<script>

    function makePage(){
    var comment = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
    alert (comment);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
    }
    var content = JSON.stringify({ comment: comment });
    xmlhttp.open("POST","makePage.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(content);
}

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$content = $data['comment'];
$file = uniqid() . ".html";
file_put_contents("userdata/$file", $content);
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: It is creating file, but with zero KB size. It is not sending even the text data.

Comment: Provide example with "HTML data" ?

Comment: https://html5andcss3.org/tryit_2.php

write some text inside textarea and it should work, but write some code of HTML inside text area and it will not work

Comment: Try with `var_dump($_POST)` in your php file it works and send whole HTML code, cuz I send JSON string, you should decode it and use it.

Comment: <?php
$content = var_dump($_POST["content"]);
$newcontent = base64_decode($content);
$file = uniqid() . ".html";
file_put_contents("userdata/$file", $newcontent);
echo $file;
?>

Something like this ?

Comment: Ok, I update the answer, just copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

Post will work this way

```
function makePage(){
   var data = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
   $.post("makePage.php", {content: data}, function(result){
      //Do something with the result
   });
};
```

Then the php

```
$content = $_POST['content'] or $_REQUEST['content']
```